# Sorting a range by the order of another list in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting

I have two tables, like this:

**Table 1**

```
  A
1 FirstPhase
2 SecondPhase
3 ThirdPhase
4 FourthPhase
```

**Table 2**

```
  A     B
1 Item1 FirstPhase
2 Item4 FourthPhase
3 Item2 SecondPhase
4 Item3 ThirdPhase
```

The result I want to achieve after sorting is:

```
  A     B
1 Item1 FirstPhase
2 Item2 SecondPhase
3 Item3 ThirdPhase
4 Item4 FourthPhase
```

How can I sort the second table by column `B` according to the order of column `A` in the first table?

Comment: You shouldn't have set this to 'Community Wiki', you probably would have got more input.  I'll see what I can figure out.

Comment: How's that? Doesn't it end up among the normal questions?

Comment: A lot of people won't take the time to figure out hard questions if they're not going to get any rep from it.  I'm pretty buried right now, but I plan on working on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step is to create a custom list.

- In Excel 2007, click on the Office Icon
- Select Excel Options - Popular - Edit custom lists
- Click on 'Import list from cells' range button
- Select your data and then press the Enter key
- Click on the Import button
- Click on OK and then OK again

To sort with a custom list.

- Select the data to sort.
- Click on  the Home tab and the Sort & Filter
- Select custom sort
- Select the column to sort on
- Then drop down on Order and select Custom List
- Select your custom list
- Click on OK and then OK again

In Code

```
Sub MakeCustomListAndSort()

Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4"), ByRow:=True
'Create the custom list

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B4").Sort Key1:=Range("B1:B4"), _
 Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
 OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1, MatchCase:=False, _
 Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
'Sort with latest custom list

Application.DeleteCustomList Application.CustomListCount
'Delete the latest custom list

End Sub
```

Comment: I took a look at the custom lists and was under the impression that they are only copied from the cells you import from, and not updated when those cells change.  Is that so?

Comment: Correct, Custom lists are not updated after creation without user intervention.

The code provides a way around this, as the range used to create the Custom list can be changed.

Comment: I managed to get it to work, thanks! However, I used `Key1:=Range("B1")` and did the sort on a named range instead.